# How would I convert a MIDI file into a string?

Tags: converters, midi

I am a coding newb (although I code Expression 2 in a game called Garry's Mod), and I need some help. 
I am trying to convert MIDIs into a string for a mickey-mouse coding language called Expression 2. This "expression 2" is a coding language in a game called Garry's Mod. 
My expression 2 code allows me to write in code to play a song.

```
#|  2  3     5  6  7     9  0     =  a  s     f  g     j  k  l     '
#| |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
#| |C#|D#|  |F#|G#|A#|  |C#|D#|  |F#|G#|A#|  |C#|D#|  |F#|G#|A#|  |C#|
#| |__|__|  |__|__|__|  |__|__|  |__|__|__|  |__|__|  |__|__|__|  |__|
#|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 
#|C |D |E |F |G |A |B |C |D |E |F |G |A |B |C |D |E |F |G |A |B |C |  |                                                            
#|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|
# q  w  e  r  t  y  u  i  o  p  [  ]  z  x  c  v  b  n  m  ,  .  /
```

This is the register for the E2 code. If I were to input string "qwertyu" into the e2, the Chip will play the notes CDEFGAB. For a long time now, I have had to manually type in the corresponding Alphabet keys to make a song.

This is what the code to play the song "Canon" by Pachelbel looks like

```
if (first()) {
    TrackSounds[1,string] = "synth/sine.wav"
    TrackVolume[1,number] = 0.8
    TrackStrings[1,string] =

"]]]]]]]]]pppp[[[[]]]]]]]]]pppp[[[[]]]]]ttttyyyyuuuuiiiioooopppp[[[["+
"pppppppiiiiooooppppppppeeeerrrrttttyyyyttttrrrrtttttttttt"+
"iiiiuuuuiiiiiiiiyyyyiiiiuuuuyyyyttttrrrrttttttt"
```

If you wonder why letters are repeated so much, it is because (this) Expression 2 reads each letter and plays the associated note for 50 ticks. Do not mind this. This is all relative. If there is a pause between notes, the pause length (pauses are spaces, in the string) is relative to the note length, and vise versa.

I want to make a program (or locate a program) that can convert a simple MIDI file into a string recognizable by my e2 code. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about problem, but have you tried [base64 encoding and decoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)? There should be a lot of libraries for that.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I know this answer is over a year late, but I just stumbled onto this question via Google, and as it turns out, I've already made a program to do exactly this back in 2009. I made a post about it in a [Wiremod Forum thread](http://www.wiremod.com/forum/finished-contraptions/15019-midi-e2-converter-2.html#post143368) about someone else's converter.

From the forum post:

> Notes:
> Drag a midi on to the application to convert it. It will output the expression2 in the same folder as the midi.
> Does not support midi type 0, this was out of laziness.
> Does not support pitch blends. This is used quite often in the first level of Contra on the NES (using the only NSF2MIDI converter I could find).
> All tracks play synth/tri.wav by default, but you can easily change it.
> You must change the interval() to 20 for the song to play at the correct speed.

You can download this converter [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B40Xy8VSKqoOZjEyck1lc1JJZk0/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-9hsdfCW28j0H6fArUb8j2Q).

I probably could have made a better converter, but it worked wonderfully for what I was using it for (converting NES music to midi and then to Expression 2)

Comment: Given that the OP is asking for a program to do something, and I happened to have written one for this purpose, an external link is really the only way to answer this. I've added a second link to my dropbox account, so it's easy to access and won't go anywhere.

Comment: Well, Dropbox is being a turd and retiring the Public folder. Link has been updated to Google Drive.